# sendmail cant send mail - Centos6/7

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, sendmail, email-bounces

I have a newly minted CentOS 6.7 box to set up sendmail on. It seems sending email but not really, no idea whats the issue could be.

What I did:

```
yum install sendmail sendmail-cf sendmail-doc sendmail-devel telnet
service sendmail start
chkconfig sendmail on
chkconfig --list sendmail
ls -l /etc/mail
telnet localhost 25
chkconfig --level 25 sendmail
service iptables stop
```

telnet connected successfully, iptables was stopped to reduce any complications.

Testing sendmail:

```
mail -v -s 'testing sendmail' myEmail@mydomain.com < /etc/passwd

2.1.0 <root@localhost.localdomain>... Sender ok </br>
2.1.5 <myEmail@mydomain.com>... Recipient ok
Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself

2.0.0 tA4Bud7a006235 Message accepted for delivery </br>
myEmail@mydomain.com... Sent (tA4Bud7a006235 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
 QUIT
2.0.0 localhost.localdomain closing connection
```

Now this shows the message have sent successfully but i cant see any email in my inbox and if ) check `/var/log/maillog`:

```
Nov  4 15:48:03 localhost sendmail[6852]: tA3HPSF2002371: to=<myEmail@myDomain.com>, ctladdr=<root@localhost.localdomain> (0/0), delay=22:22:35, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=2732098, relay=mail.myDomain.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by mail.mydomain.com.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for correct format text Fuero. i first time posted question.

Answer (score 0):

As `maillog` states:

You are trying to send to `myDomain.com`, sendmail doesn't think it is its job to handle mails for that domain, so it forwards them to `mail.mydomain.com` (taken from the MX record for that domain), which in turn doesn't seem to have a mailserver present on port 25.

A little more detail on the domains and the config involved might help.

Comment: sorry its fortesecurities.com i changed it as myDomain.com

Comment: Any Solution...